# Is it possible to make the Mongo PHP extension throw Exceptions, like PDO's PDO::ERRMODE_EXEPTION?

Tags: php, mongodb

I prefer my programs to fail early and fail hard if I neglect to error check for something. Unfortunately, the Mongo extension requires me to constantly check `MongoDb->lastError()`. Is there an easy way to emulate `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXEPTION)` with Mongo?

Preferably something that doesn't involve writing wrapper classes for everything, which I'd rather only do if I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. Please file a feature request at http://jira.mongodb.org for this.

Comment: I've added an issue. Thanks, Derick

Comment: I didn't see it pop-up. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 4):

> the Mongo extension requires me to constantly check `MongoDb->lastError()`

So what's actually going on here is a little more subtle.

By default, MongoDB operates in "fire and forget" mode. So it sends a write to the server (*fire*) and then simply trusts that the server will handle it (*forget*). This is the default configuration for all writes for all of the drivers.

You want exceptions, so you need to issue your updates in "safe" mode. Under safe mode, the driver automatically issues the `lastError()` command before returning control to the caller.

You can set safe mode on individual operations:

```
$collection->insert(array("x" => 1), array("safe" => true));
```

The driver should support setting this on the connection level, but for some reason is does not. So you will have to add that `array('safe' => true)` everywhere.

> Preferably something that doesn't involve writing wrapper classes for everything...

Unfortunately, I think this is inevitable. "Safe" mode is just the start. In "safe" mode, you are only guaranteed a commit to memory on the primary server. If you want to ensure that data is on disk you need to use "fsync" or "journal". If you are running replica sets and you want to ensure data is in two places you will need to use some "w" option.

Also, if you are using Replica Sets (*which 10gen recommends for all production deployments*), then you will have to handle an exception when the primary goes down. Generally you want to retry the connection as opening the new connection should force a new connection to the new primary.

This, along with a host of other tweaks typically means that your code will devolve into needing some type of wrapper class because of the various exception cases you will need to handle.